# How can I add data from Access datatable to another access empty datatable with different columns

Tags: c#, ms-access, datatable

I have a problem to get data from datatable 1 to empty datatable 2 with different column names.

datatable 1

```
countrycode  country
0031         Netherlands
0032         Belgium
```

datatable 2

```
LandenID    Landnummer  Landnaam    ....
(empty)
```

result should be

datatable 2

```
LandenID    Landnummer  Landnaam    ....
1           0031        Netherlands
2           0032        Belgium
```

I have tried code below, but with no success

```csharp
    public void CopyImport2CT(string myTable)
    {
        //Copy data Importtable to Landentabel
        try
        {
            // Create the dataset and add the Categories table to it:
            DataSet myProviderDs = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection mycopy2CTConn = null;
            try
            {
                mycopy2CTConn = new OleDbConnection(strProviderConn);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to create a database connection. \n{0}", ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
            string copystring = "select * from " + myTable;
            OleDbCommand myProviderCommand = new OleDbCommand(copystring, mycopy2CTConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter ca = new OleDbDataAdapter(myProviderCommand);
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(myTable);
            dt1.Columns.Add("Countrycode");
            dt1.Columns.Add("Country");
            dt1.Columns.Add("Highfee");
            dt1.Columns.Add("Lowfee");
            dt1.Columns.Add("Weekendfee");
            ca.Fill(ds1);
            Console.WriteLine(ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
            mycopy2CTConn.Open();
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Landentabel");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Landnummer");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Landnaam");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Piektarief");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Daltarief");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Weekendtarief");
            OleDbConnection myCTConn = null;
            try
            {
                myCTConn = new OleDbConnection(strProviderConn);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to create a database connection. \n{0}", ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }


            for (int k = 0; k < ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; k++)
            {
                dt2.Rows.Add.[k]["Landnummer"] = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[k]["Countrycode"];
                dt2.Rows.Add.[k]["Landnaam"] = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[k]["Country"];
                dt2.Rows.Add.[k]["Piektarief"] = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[k]["Highfee"];
                dt2.Rows.Add.[k]["Daltarief"] = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[k]["Lowfee"];
                dt2.Rows.Add.[k]["Weekendtarief"] = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[k]["Weekendfee"];
            }

            mycopy2CTConn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to create a database connection. \n{0}", ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you could try creating an instance of a datarow and then adding the data row to the datatable 2, this wont work because your assuming there are rows that can be indexed through [k] in datatable 2 when it contains no rows.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to do this.

```
public void CopyImport2CT(string myTable)
{
    //Copy data Importtable to Landentabel
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection mycopy2CTConn = new OleDbConnection(strProviderConn))
        {
            string copystring = "INSERT INTO Landentabel (LandenID, Landnummer, Landnaam, Piektarief, Daltarief, Weekendtarief) SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + myTable + " WHERE e.CountryCode >= CountryCode) AS Id, e.CountryCode, e.Country, e.HighFee, e.LowFee, e.Weekendfee from " + myTable + " e ORDER BY e.CountryCode";
            using (OleDbCommand myProviderCommand = new OleDbCommand(copystring, mycopy2CTConn))
            {
                mycopy2CTConn.Open();
                myProviderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to create a copy data. \n{0}", ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

This assumes that LandenID is not an AutoNumber.  If it is an AutoNumber, then it becomes even easier.  Change copystring to:

```
string copystring = "INSERT INTO Landentabel (Landnummer, Landnaam, Piektarief, Daltarief, Weekendtarief) SELECT e.CountryCode, e.Country, e.HighFee, e.LowFee, e.Weekendfee from " + myTable + " e";
```

Some explanation.

Firstly DbConnection and DbCommand both implement IDisposable.  This means that the recommended way to handle them is within a using () section, so that the Garbage Collector knows instantly when the objects can safely be disposed.  Moe importantly for you as a developer is that you do not need to concern yourself with disposing the objects.

Secondly, one SQL command inserts all the entries into the target table.  This is a much faster method.  The general syntax is INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM.
My first example assumes that LandenID is an integer but not an AutoNumber.  AutoNumbers are a pet hate of mine, so I provide some useful syntax for deriving the row number in Access (Access does not have an inbuilt ROW_NUMBER function as do other dbs like SQL Server).  If you are using AutoNumber though, just replace this with the second definition of copystring.

Thirdly, I have followed you in passing the name of the source table as a string parameter.  However, unless you have very good reason to do so, I encourage you not to.  Why?  Firstly, you need to know the column names of myTable in your code.  If you know the column names, why wouldn't you know the table name?  Why does this need to be a parameter?  Secondly, and more importantly building SQL queries in this way, i.e. creating a string and inserting into this string a string parameter, is opening yourself up to SQL Injection.  If you do not know what this is, I encourage you to Google it.  Actually for a technical reason to do with the fact that Access accepts only a single command at a time, Access is relatively safe from the worst forms of SQL Injection.  Nevertheless, I strongly encourage you (for yours and everyone else's safety) to get into the habit of writing code that does not have this potential weakness.

Comment: Nice trick re: `(SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE e.CountryCode >= CountryCode)`. Just for safety, I think I'd use `... FROM (SELECT * FROM " + myTable + " ORDER BY countrycode) e"` for the outer SELECT just to make sure that the rows from the source table come out in the right order.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks.  Very good point.  I have amended my answer accordingly.